# Should I use ref when modifying the content of an object passed as a parameter

Tags: c#

Suppose we have a function `MutateX` which will mutate a mutable object `x` *(in my case a byte[])*, which unsurprisingly changes `x`'s state. I can define `MutateX` in two ways

```
void MutateX (ref Object x);  // (A)
// or
void MutateX (Object x);      // (B)
```

X being a reference value anyway - either will work although.

To me `ref` indicates that the function is going to change `x` in some way (whether or not it changes the actual reference value to some other Object). Is there one form preferred over the other?

*I notice that in SerialPort.Read is implemented without*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are only changing the *state* of the **object** (i.e. not reassigning the reference, but setting properties / calling methods / etc), then no: don't use `ref`.

> To me ref indicates that the function is going to change x in some way

Indeed it does! But you *aren't* changing `x` - you are changing to object *referred to* by `x`, which is a different thing.

Use `ref` if:

- changing the reference itself (for reference-types)
- changing the state of a value-type (yuck, should be immutable, or use the return value of the method, which may be simpler)

So in short; "no". Actually, `ref` is pretty uncommon and poorly understood, which is *another* reason to minimise use of it unless necessary.

Answer (score 2):

`ref` should be used only when you change the parameter itself - in this case, x itself, not the contents of x.

**Code is to be read and understood.**, do not use keywords for other purposes than they are intended to. You'd confuse everyone else who reads your code - and that might include you in five years.  It's not even a case of preference, it's simply wrong, wrong, wrong.

What you are looking for is actually `const` - which isn't implemented in .NET, partly because (as every C++ programmer can tell you) it's an incomplete and tricky beast.

If you DO think this is important, you could use your own nomenclature consistently, and document it with the project rules, e.g.

```
void UseX(Object constX) { ... }
void MutateX(Object x)  { ... }
```

Comment: You are correct, I'm looking for const. I was actually considering asking if anyone had a link to some form of discussion as to why its not implemented. I seem to rememberer seeing one back when I was first trying to see if existed under some other guise.

Comment: Heijlsberg discusses this here: http://www.artima.com/intv/choicesP.html. I'd love to see one that is checked by the compiler (rather than runtime, as Heijlsberg implies) - but as a mostly C++ programmer I know how much it complicates *other* aspects of the language so I accept it's been left out.

Answer (score 1):

No - if you only need to modify properties of or the contents of the object passed, you don't need ref. An object instance of a class is passed as a reference anyway - you can totally change it inside your code.

You need ref when you want to actually instantiate the object inside your method - in that case, you're not modifying a property of the object passed in, you're actually modifying the object itself (its instance, by creating it).

Comment: s/instantiate/reassign, but I agree.